# Как определить является ли сумма трёх чисел чётным числом кратным X?

Tags: c++, математика

Даны 3 числа. Определить, является ли их сумма четным числом,
кратным .
Вот мой код:

```
//Даны 3 числа. Определить, является ли их сумма четным числом,кратным .
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int a, b, c,x,s;
    cout << "Введите три числа и X: \n";
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> x;
    s = (a + b + c) % x && ((a +b +c) % 2 ==0);
      
    cout << a << "+" << b << "+" << c << "=" << s << endl;    
}
```

Что тут не так?Тут и проверка суммы на кратность X и проверка на чётность,не пойму в чём проблема,помогите решить.

Answer (score 0):

вот этот код означает, что число не кратно x

```
(a + b + c) % x
```

вы же сами записали

```
s = (a + b + c) % x && 
   ((a + b + c) % 2 == 0);
```

почему же у вас кратность x и кратность 2 отличаются сравнениями :)

если число делится без остатка на другое число, то модуль деления должен быть равен нулю, поэтому и сравнивать надо с нулём

если же этого не делать, что любое иное число кроме 0 будет восприниматься как `true` и значит проверка будет проверять некратность числа, а не кратность

Comment: Zhihar,хм,любопытно,мне получается записать всё под одними скобками?

Comment: если число делится без остатка, то его модуль равен 0 - ну и надо проверить модуль на 0, если модуль не равен нулю, то число некратное, то `if (число)` будет всегда правдиво, только если число не равно 0, поэтому и надо было писать `(a + b + c) % x == 0`, т.е. вся проверка выглядела бы  `((a + b + c) % x == 0) && ((a +b +c) % 2 ==0)` ну и конечно вопрос к тому что вы выводите

Comment: Zhihar,вывожу результат то есть является ли сумма чисел кратна X и чётные ли это числа.

Comment: и чему результат будет равен - какой именно у вас вывод будет?

Comment: У меня вывод получился что сумма равна нулю.

Comment: конечно, а вы что ожидаете - у вас или 0 или 1 будет только выводиться, поскольку s по сути является булевым

Comment: Zhihar,то есть мне нужно просто сделать так:если сумма кратна x и если она чётная то выводить её,так?

Comment: а что именно вам надо вывести и в каком виде? до того как код писать какое задание было?

Comment: Zhihar,задание такое:дано три числа.Проверить их сумму на кратность X и тна то чётная от это сумма.Вот и всё задание.

Comment: ну и что по вашему надо выводить если 1) сумма кратна и чётна 2) сумма не кратна или не чётна?

Comment: Zhihar,выводить надо сумма кратна и чётна

Comment: ох, возьмите бумажку и напишите как должна работать программа - что в нее должны вводить, что и в каком виде выводиться. `выводить надо сумма кратна и чётна` - это на каком языке написано? Если сумма кратна и чётна, то что должно вывестись на экран? Если сумма некратна, что должно вывестись на экран? Вот вы сами как представляете работу свой программы?

Comment: Zhihar,if (sum%2==0 && sum%X==0) cout << "YES\n"; это мы выводим Yes иначе No.Вот вроде так.

Comment: вот так лучше! а вначале был вывод о совсем другом `if (...) std::cout << "YES" << std::endl else std::cout << "NO" << std::endl`

Answer (score 0):

Так будет понятней для случайных посетителей этого вопроса.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{    
    int a, b, c, X;
    cout << "Enter integer a, b, c, X:\n";
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> X;
    
    if ((a + b + c) % 2 == 0 && (a + b + c) % X == 0)
        cout << "YES\n";
    else
        cout << "NO\n";
      
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Тут проверяется кратна ли сумма X и чётна ли она.

Comment: Приоритеты операций!

Comment: EOF,что не так с приоритетами?

Comment: `a+b+c%2==0 && a+b+c%X==0` тоже самое что и `a+b+(c%2)==0 && a+b+(c%X)==0`

Comment: EOF,я так понимаю у меня приоритет нарушен или что?

Comment: Ну Вам же нужно проверить сумму на чётность и кратность, а не только `c`. Нужно `(a+b+c)%2==0 && (a+b+c)%X==0`. Ну и переменную `sum` Вы никак не используете.

Comment: EOF,понял спасибо за указание на банальную ошибку

Comment: А зачем 2 раза считать сумму?